# Custom shapes as buttons Windows 8

Tags: xaml, window

I'm trying to make a custom button with the shape of some countries in an application for Windows 8, I´ve put a path as  button content. The problem I'm having is that hovering the mouse over the button I  have this  square edge (board) like in the image, I would like to do something like 3rd image in the link. Anyone have any idea how to do this? I'm accepting all possible ideas, thank you all for your attention.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FB358590F3727A63!183&authkey=!AHwzOa2dQPSj338

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
<Style x:Key="BasicRichTextStyle" TargetType="RichTextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.StylisticSet20" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.CaseSensitiveForms" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

and u can use visualstatemanager to set property for the Hover property i think so

Answer (score 0):

While styling the button check for the border which is wrapping the content presenter. Try changing the border color or thickness property on PointOver Viewstate or if you dont need it at all you can completely remove the border thickness for all states like this,

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```